# Maintaining passed i value in a for loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

So I have a multifile uploader I'm working on and I have trouble maintaining the `i` form the `for` loop.
Basically the problem is that I pass the `i` value in the progressHandler function but everytime the progressHandler fires it fires with the last `i` value which would be `files.files.length`.

What is the best way to keep the `i` value passed in the first place?

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.files.length; i++) {
    ...
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){progressHandler(event,i)}, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){completeHandler(event,i)}, false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need to use a closure, there are many examples for that, one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture i in a closure, check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures) for a good guide on using them. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.files.length; i++) {
    ...
    (function (i) {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){progressHandler(event,i)}, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){completeHandler(event,i)}, false);
    }
    ...
}
```